# Queue implementation in Odersky Scala book. Chapter 19

Tags: scala

I see this code on page 388 of the Odersky book on Scala:

```
class SlowAppendQueue[T](elems: List[T]) {
  def head = elems.head
  def tail = new SowAppendQueue(elems.tail)
  def enqueue(x: T) = new SlowAppendQueue(elems ::: List(x))
}

class SlowHeadQueue[T](smele: List[T]) {
  def head = smele.last
  def tail = new SlowHeadQueue(smele.init)
  def enqueue(x: T) = new SlowHeadQueue(x :: smele)
}
```

Is the following correct to say:

1. Both implementations of `tail` takes time proportional to the number of elements in the queue.
2. The second implementation of head is slower than the first. The second implementation takes time proportional to the length of the queue. Why is this? How is it implemented? Is it like a linked list where each element has a pointer to the next?

Why does Odersky say the second class' implementation of `tail` is problematic but not the first?

Comment: I believe that it is an example just for exercising of programming FP structures in Scala. In the real world queues are used to bypass messages between threads. See JCTools libraries for best implementations of different variations of them: https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk It's true that that's a typical use for concurrent queues, but queues are also used for a number of algorithms, including BFS and Dijkstra's.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Dijkstra's algorithm requires priority queues like Fibonacci heaps, this is an entirely different beast. Unfortunately, after all those decades, there still seems to be no Fibonacci heap in the standard library (neither in Java, nor in Scala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. In the first case, `tail` works in constant time, because `elems.tail` is a constant time operation (it just returns the the tail of the list). The constructor `new SlowAppendQueue(...)` is also a constant time operation, because it just wraps the list.
2. Because if `smele` has `N > 1` elements, then `smele.init` must rebuild a new list with `N - 1` elements from scratch. This takes linear time, therefore it is much slower than the `O(1)` operation from the first queue implementation.
3. `O(N)` operations are problematic because they are slow for large `N`, whereas `O(1)` operations are essentially never problematic.

I think you should take a closer look into how the immutable single-linked list is implemented, and what it takes to prepend an element (`O(1)`), append an element (`O(N)`), to access the tail (`O(1)`), rebuild the `init` (`O(N)`). Then everything else becomes obvious.

Comment: For 1. How is tail implemented? Does it not have to traverse the whole list to get to the tail? Oh... it just returns the list from index 1 to the back right?

Comment: @Jwan622 Take a look at [cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists). Single-linked lists in functional programming languages have been implemented in this way since time immemorial. To access head, you simply return the first pointer. To access `tail`, you simply return second pointer. Both operations are O(1).

Comment: @Jwan622 Just as an additional remark on the epicness of this data structure: [take a look at this user pic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2046372/cairnarvon)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, the first `tail` implementation takes constant time. This is because `List.tail` is a constant time operation due to structural sharing, and wrapping the list in a new `SlowAppendQueue` is also a constant time operation.
2. The second implementation of `head` takes constant time because of the way functional linked lists (including Scala's `List` class) work. Each list node has a link to the node after it. In order to remove the last element via `init`, the entire list must be rebuilt.

In summary, `List` is fast when operating on the beginning, but not when solely operating on the end. See also the [Scala docs for List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html).